# Is it possible to use azureml without any login things?

Tags: azure

To run sklearn, auto-sklearn on my local machine, I just need to `pip install` them, no need for login to anything.

To run [azureml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-environment#feedback), it seems to need login somewhere and finish a bunch of things if I am a new user to azure.com.

Is it possible to use azureml as simple as sklearn, just `pip install` it without any login things?

```
from azureml.core import Workspace

subscription_id = '<subscription-id>'
resource_group  = '<resource-group>'
workspace_name  = '<workspace-name>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use any of the services/products in Azure you need to have the login credentials. As you see you need to provide the subscription id and the workspace name is needed in order to run your ML model or whatever. In order to run those command you must login with your credentials. sklearn is a python library whereas Azure ML is a complete product/service which needs to have security integrated in place.

Comment: Thank you. Does MS/Azure provide some python libraries like auto-sklearn rather than a service for AutoML?